# Oracle connection using Spring jdbc template, ORA-12514

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jdbc

I am very new to Spring JDBC template. I am trying to run a sort of hello world program.

My issues is if I define url as :

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@some_host:1521:some_service
```

it works perfectly fine, however defining like below throws the above mentioned error.

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION= 
   (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=some_host) (PORT=1521)) 
   (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=some_service)))
```

Here is my `beans.xml`, What am I doing wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd ">

    <bean id="dataSource" class="oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceFactory" factory-method="getPoolDataSource">
        <property name="URL" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION= 
            (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=some_host) (PORT=1521)) 
            (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=some_service)))" />
    <!--  property name="URL" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@some_host:1521:some_service" /> -->
        <property name="User" value="some_user" />
        <property name="Password" value="some_password" />
        <property name="ConnectionFactoryClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.replay.OracleDataSourceImpl" />
        <property name="ConnectionPoolName" value="mypool" />
        <property name="MinPoolSize" value="1" />
        <property name="MaxPoolSize" value="20" />
        <property name="InitialPoolSize" value="1" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Definition for studentJDBCTemplate bean -->
    <bean id="studentJDBCTemplate" class="StudentJDBCTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: If you're new to Spring, get started with Spring Boot instead of manual configuration. It handles most of the boilerplate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the connection string `:some_service` means the SID(the service name is placed after `/`). So if the `jdbc:oracle:thin:@some_host:1521:some_service` is correct then some_service is the SID name, the service name is probably something else.

See here http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/JDBC

You can use something like

```
ORCL =
 (DESCRIPTION =
   (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = myhost)(PORT = 1521))
   (CONNECT_DATA =
     (SID = ORCL)
   )
 )
```

Comment: Ah! perfect. I changed SERVICE_NAME to SID and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is not legal to use a CR and/or LF in a XML attribute value.

So remove that from

`<property name="URL" value="...no CR/LF here ..."`